# Is it bad coding style to overwrite variable names?

Tags: variables, coding-style, styles

When writing quick, get-er-done scripts, I often overwrite variable names once I don't need them anymore. Is this bad?  It saves memory, in the same way recycling a soda can saves the planet.

Comment: Ok, I believe the net of the discussion is that it does not, in fact, save memory, and that it is bad coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does it save memory to overwrite a variable as opposed to disposing of it properly and declaring a new one. Do you have any experience with the mechanics of assembly? I believe the only thing you save by doing it your way is typing. Code readability suffers when you don't choose unique variables as you get further down the script.

Take for example a book that reuses page 1 all the way through to the page of a 300 page book. How easy would it be to recall your position?

In reference to your comparison of reusing variables and recycling. Variables are relative spaces of memory that are dissipated completely as though they never existed upon destruction, where as plastics and paper will always leave some sort of footprint even if it is in the form of a physical shift, such as a solid to a gas.

I would recommend declaring only the amount of variables needed to get the job done, but as many as it takes to improve code readability. Unless there is some alternative motivation.

**I look at variables like plates at the buffet, once your done... Get a new one.**

Comment: I haven't ever gotten into assembly; are you saying that overwriting the variable doesn't save memory at all?  Also, I think people are taking my recycling comment a little too seriously.

Comment: Reusing a variable name will not save memory. The name is nothing but a pointer to the contents in memory. Each new value will have memory associated with it regardless of what it is. There's a lot of nuance to this once you dig into a specific language but generally is a reasonable approximation.

Comment: Yeah as said above, in a very basic metaphore. When you declare a variable it gets a virtual house, the address to that house is stored away in memory and as soon as you sign the eviction notice to release the variable back to the computer, its like the variable never existed... Unless some remanents were sent to storage in the form of a file. You should check out assembly and basic logic gates. It amazed me when I started discovering the magic behind computers is not magic at all and when you put them under a very focused scope, they are surprisingly simple... Like On or Off simple.

Comment: I warn you the further into the rabbit hole you go, the more addicted you become.

Comment: Yeah, I'd actually *like* to dive into Assembly someday, understand how it all works.  As you can see from my previous question about developing NES roms, it's not my first priority.  Specifically, I had Python in mind when asking the question, which is implemented in C, and I don't know if/how they implement some kind of a garbage collection apparatus, ala Java, to decommission memory.  In any case, thank you muchly.